# authenticate docker for gcp artifact registry in bazel test

Tags: docker, bazel, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I have a bazel test that `docker build` and `docker push` to google artifact registry a docker image. It fails, because "cannot create private file:
/home/bill/.config/gcloud/credentials.db".

I can turn off bazel sandboxing by either using `local=True` in bazel rule or avoid `docker push` (i.e. test with local image). Is there some better work-around?

Comment: You can use Bazel's `--sandbox_writable_path`flag. Check this [link1](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html) &  [link2](https://www.tumblr.com/jorgar/187522995384/ccache-and-bazel?source=share)

Comment: That works! Is it possible to specify that on a per test rule basis, as only the `py_test` that calls docker push need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bazel's `--sandbox_writable_path` flag to explicitly specify the path. As mentioned in this [Bazel's doc](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--sandbox_writable_path)

> For sandboxed actions, make an existing directory writable in the sandbox (if supported by the sandboxing implementation, ignored otherwise).
>
> `--sandbox_writable_path`, which asks the sandbox to make an existing directory writable when running actions.

Seems the flag  `--sandbox_writable_path` applies to the entire build process, Not  possible to specify  on a per test rule basis.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not doing a `docker push` from within a `bazel build` or `bazel test` rule, because it has side-effects (namely, an image may become present on a remote server). Generally speaking, this can cause issues:

- other teams/devs may not be aware that a particular build/test target has these side effects. In this specific case, pushing to a particular tag is problematic if anything depends on the tag, because it could change the tagged version without warning, and it becomes harder to reason about what code/image the tag currently points to
- concurrent runs of a test target (e.g. with `--runs_per_test=10`) with side effects can cause a race on the external system; the state on the external system may be indeterminate, or the test target may spuriously fail if the external system errors when races occur
- build outputs/test results may not be cacheable (one is trying to rerun the test to execute the side effect, but bazel is trying to aggressively cache the test result, for instance)

Commands with side-effects are best put inside a script/binary and triggered via `bazel run` instead. This does complicate end-to-end-type flows, that may need to execute more than one bazel step to complete; however, it keeps a clear delineation between bazel invocations that are not expected to have side effects vs. those that might, which will line up better with user and tool expectations.